# R Paste0 with NaN removal

Tags: r, nan

I have the following code to create my df:

```
tab9 <- table(tab9data %>%
  select(currentGrade, percentDiffRange) %>%
  group_by(currentGrade)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'percentDiffRange', values_from = 'Freq') %>%
  mutate(perc0 = round((tab9$`0%`/ rowSums(tab9[ ,2:6])) * 100,1),
         perc0.1_1.9 = round((tab9$`0.1% - 1.9%`/ rowSums(tab9[ ,2:6])) * 100,1),
         perc2_3.9 = round((tab9$`2% - 3.9%`/ rowSums(tab9[ ,2:6])) * 100,1),
         perc4_5.9 = round((tab9$`4% - 5.9%`/ rowSums(tab9[ ,2:6])) * 100,1),
         perc6 = round((tab9$`6% or more`/ rowSums(tab9[ ,2:6])) * 100,1))

tab9[is.na(tab9)] <- 0
```

I want to paste0 an "%" symbol to the percent values in my 5 mutated columns. However, when I paste0 the "%" symbol into each column the 'NaN's in the columns are turned to 'NaN%' and which stops this line of code working:

```
tab9[is.na(tab9)] <- 0
```

How do I add the percentage symbol while still turning the NaN's to 0?

Thanks

Comment: `tab9[tab9 == "NaN%"] <- 0`

Comment: That is causing the following error: Error:
! Assigned data `0` must be compatible with existing data.
ℹ Error occurred for column `perc0`.
✖ Can't convert <double> to <character>.
Backtrace:
  1. base::`[<-`(`*tmp*`, tab9 == "NaN%", value = `<dbl>`)
 19. tibble (local) `<fn>`(`<vctrs_r_>`)

Comment: `tab9` is a `tibble` and is strict to column types. Try `tab9[tab9 == "NaN%"] <- "0"`

Comment: That has worked - thank you very much!

Comment: That's why you should avoid `tibbles`